# Multiple Web API 2 apps in one solution, both using Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I have two Web API 2 projects, `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` inside one solution.

They are independent projects. I want to use ninject in both, but these lines are causing problems.

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(ProjectA.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
```

and

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(ProjectB.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
```

Even if I have only ProjectA as the startup project, both NinjectWebCommon classes will execute. And whichever runs last (usually ProjectB) overwrites what was done by the first.

**The exception:**

When calling `bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel)` in the ProjectB I get -

`"Sequence contains no elements"`

How can I have two projects, either of which, or both, could be startup projects in the one solution using ninject?

**The Code**

This is my `NinjectWebCommon`, it is almost identical for ProjectA and ProjectB, just the registered services differ.

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(ProjectA.WebApi.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(ProjectA.WebApi.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace ProjectA.WebApi.App_Start
{

    public static class NinjectWebCommon
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

                RegisterServices(kernel);

                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            var mapper = AutoMapperConfig.SetupMappings();
            kernel.Bind<IMapper>().ToConstant(mapper);

            kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>();
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing just how distinct projects would interfere with each other like this. Perhaps there is something in the init methods you have created that we need to see?

Comment: @DavidG Added the NinjectWebCommon to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been one of those unfortunate cases where Visual Studio 2015 was holding on to some old version(s) of dlls and executing the wrong code in the debugger. I am not 100% sure of this but fairly certain.

In a new solution I created two Web API projects, added ninject to both, registered some services, set both as startup project and everything worked without a problem.

Back in the damaged solution I noticed that that debugger was executing lines of code from classes in a project that was unloaded! I tried deleting cached versions of dlls from many places on the hard disk, but this didn't help.

**To resolve the problem**
Looks like my Visual Studio 2015 (Update 2) is not deleting temporary files correctly. I manually deleted files in -

`c:\Users\bryan\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs`

and

`c:\Users\bryan\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root`

Comment: How has having multiple web api projects in one solution been working out for you? I have been thinking about doing this.  Do you have to set up Ninject to both projects separately or can you have a shared project that can reference the two consuming projects? If you have to treat the two projects separately, what is the advantage of having one solution? Is it just to have shared utilities and classes?

Comment: No problem to have two (or more) Web Api projects in a solution. Each gets its own ninject class, packages, dlls etc. I suggest not putting ninject into its own project and sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with Ninject because if the projects are independent even if they are in the same solution that should work. So just remove one of the project
and then build the solution. Make sure it builds first then you can add a new project in the solution then build it again. Then you can add Ninject package again. Are you using nuget to download/install the package in your project?

Comment: If comment out one of the - 
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(ProjectA.WebApi.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")] the other project works.